# Diverging integral?

Tags: integration

If I have $\int_{a}^{b} f(x)$ with $a < c < b$. We have that

$\int_{a}^{b} f(x) = \int_{a}^{c} f(x) + \int_{c}^{b} f(x)$

If say $\int_{a}^{c} f(x)$ diverges, can we conclude $\int_a^b f(x)$ also diverges?

Comment: It depends a little bit on how exactly you decide to define everything, but typically yes.

Comment: Please [choose a good title](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question#10144) for your question.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can get that conclusion. Here are some counterexamples.

Let $f(x)=1/x$, $a=-1, b=1, c=0$, apparently the integral converges to 0. (its negative part offsets its positive part)

continuous on (a,b) case: $f(x)=tan(x)$, $a=-pi/2, b=pi/2, c=0$. Also the integral converges to 0 for the same reason.

Comment: These are Cauchy Principal Value integrals, not Riemann Integrals, so it depends on how you define the integrals.